# Failed to load ApplicationContext in Spring

Tags: java, xml, spring, applicationcontext

Failing to Load Application Context 
Below is my Spring Configuration File:  `spring-context.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
 xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
https://www.springframework.org/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<task:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />
<import resource="application/environment.xml" />

<context:spring-configured/>
<context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.mypackage" />
</beans>
```

Below is the Error Log

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
         at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) ~[spring-test-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117) ~[spring-test-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228) [spring-test-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230) [spring-test-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit.jar:?]
         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249) [spring-test-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89) [spring-test-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit.jar:?]
         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit.jar:?]
         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit.jar:?]
         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit.jar:?]
         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit.jar:?]
         at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26) [junit.jar:?]
         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit.jar:?]
         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193) [spring-test-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter.run(JUnit4TestAdapter.java:38) [junit.jar:?]
         at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:535) [ant-junit.jar:?]
         at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(JUnitTestRunner.java:1182) [ant-junit.jar:?]
         at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.main(JUnitTestRunner.java:1033) [ant-junit.jar:?]
     Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 12 in XML document from URL [file:configuration/spring-configuration/spring-config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 115; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399) ~[spring-beans-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336) ~[spring-beans-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181) ~[spring-beans-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217) ~[spring-beans-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188) ~[spring-beans-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252) ~[spring-beans-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:253) ~[spring-test-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:122) ~[spring-test-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60) ~[spring-test-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109) ~[spring-test-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261) ~[spring-test-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-test-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) ~[spring-test-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         ... 24 more
     Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1900) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:740) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:613) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3132) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:852) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76) ~[spring-beans-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429) ~[spring-beans-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391) ~[spring-beans-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336) ~[spring-beans-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181) ~[spring-beans-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217) ~[spring-beans-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188) ~[spring-beans-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252) ~[spring-beans-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:253) ~[spring-test-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:122) ~[spring-test-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60) ~[spring-test-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109) ~[spring-test-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261) ~[spring-test-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-test-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) ~[spring-test-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
         ... 24 more
     Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.395 sec
```

Comment: Replace the `https` with `http` in your declaration.

Comment: After replacing it show same error at line where i replaced https

Comment: and instead of `/beans/` use `/schema/beans/` in your URL. .

Comment: used   /schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd .  Same error at same line

Comment: Do u have the xsd definition which  can use instead of this

Comment: Don't add code as comments that makes it unreadable.

Comment: Those namespaces are mentioned in the documentation and also a decent IDE will help you with that.

Comment: IDE doesnt show any error , i feel it is not able to find bean locations which i have created thought Java Class

Answer (score 0):

you can try this below code :-

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-
  context.xsd">
```